# ConTeXt: Protrusion inside enumeration

Tags: context, protrusion

I cannot get protrusion to work inside enumerations. I’m creating a presentation, and most of the content is inside an itemize environment. I have searched all over, in the wiki, the ’Fonts out of ConTeXt’ manual, the mailing list, but found no mention of this problem.

```
\setuppapersize[S3]
\showframe

\definefontfeature [default] [default] [protrusion=quality]
\setupalign[hanging]

\setupitemize[margin] % To compare the two better

\starttext
  “The quote on this line is visibly protruding.”
  \startitemize
    \item “This one, however, is not.”
  \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image: rendered PDF]

How can I enable protrusion inside enumerations? Or, if there is no standard way, can I hack it around somehow?

Comment: Just to clarify the issue, protrusion works (if you change the sentence to `“This one, however, is not visibly protruding.”`, you will see that the hyphen protrudes to the margin. The starting quote, though, does not protrude. I am not a font expert, so don't know the reason or have a work-around. You  could also try asking on the context mailing list

Comment: Huh, you’re right. Thanks, I’ll try asking on the mailing list.

Comment: My bet is that it doesn't protrude because `“` is not actually the first character in that line.  The first character is the box containing the bullet that is shifted into the margin.  I guess in principle one could work around that by placing the bullet with `\vadjust` or so, but that would require extensive surgery on the ConTeXt core.